# Zipfile in vb.net 4.5 "The directory name is invalid." error - can't identify the cause?

Tags: vb.net, compression, zip

I've got a small utility that can encrypt/decrypt using .net 4.5 TripleDES routines. I added compression and found the simpler compression stuff doesn't work for me.

The files referenced in these fields definitely exist, aren't huge at all and are even named in the same case.

Yet I keep getting  "The directory name is invalid.". If I take out the test for existence of the archive, I get a different error - as it's made the zip and it's 0 bytes. I've searched for far longer on this than it took to work out how to use the encryption part of my utility yesterday - and that's with learning how streams work!

Can anyone shed light on this issue at all please?

```
Private Encoded As String = "C:\TestFile\encoded.txt"
Private Decoded As String = "C:\TestFile\decoded.txt"
Private CompressEncoded As String = "C:\TestFile\encoded.zip"

Private Sub Main()
  Compress(Encoded, CompressEncoded)
End sub

Sub Compress(filename As String, zippedFile As String)
'Added to handle file already exists error
  If IO.File.Exists(zippedFile) Then IO.File.Delete(zippedFile)
  If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filename, zippedFile, CompressionLevel.Fastest, True)
End Sub
```

In addition to this code I also tried adding a quick streamreader test to prove to myself that filename does exist. 
'      Dim sr As New StreamReader(filename)
       MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd)

It does and displays the line of text within it.

I'd be grateful for any help - this rather silly bug has chewed up lots of time this afternoon that I was hoping to use on something more useful :).

Thanks folks!

Thanks for the answer!

```
Sub Compress(filename As String, zippedFile As String)
    If IO.File.Exists(zippedFile) Then IO.File.Delete(zippedFile)

    If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Using archive As ZipArchive = Open(zippedFile, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filename, Path.GetFileName(filename), CompressionLevel.Fastest)
        End Using

    End If
End Sub

Sub Decompress(ZippedFile As String, UnzippedFile As String)
    If IO.File.Exists(UnzippedFile) Then IO.File.Delete(UnzippedFile)

    If IO.File.Exists(ZippedFile) Then
        Using archive As ZipArchive = Open(ZippedFile, ZipArchiveMode.Read)
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(UnzippedFile))
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compress a single file, use [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) class like below:

```
Sub Compress(filename As String, zippedFile As String)
    If IO.File.Exists(zippedFile) Then IO.File.Delete(zippedFile)

    If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zippedFile, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filename, Path.GetFileName(filename), CompressionLevel.Fastest)
        End Using

    End If
End Sub
```

### ADDITIONAL INFO

Need to add reference to **System.IO.Compression.dll** for the `ZipArchive` and **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll** for the `ZipFile` class. These DLLs are not referenced by default when a project is created in VS.

Comment: @ajackblackgoat thank you. This resolved it, though it needs a .net 4 reference to system.io according to my refactor pro - I couldn't see the ZipArchive member until I did. I've updated my question, with my final implementation, so thank you.

Comment: yeah. forgot to tell you need to add reference to **System.IO.Compression** for the `ZipArchive` and **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem** for the `ZipFile` class.

Comment: @ajakblackgoat, We were trying to create a small service to zip and move oracle .dmp files based on the latest time stamp and your answer has really saved us, else were struggling with "CreateFromDirectory"

Answer (score 3):

Probably it is a simple error.
The first parameter to pass to [CreateFromDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721.aspx) should be a directory name, but you pass a file name.

Try with

```
 If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then 
      IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename), _
                        zippedFile, CompressionLevel.Fastest, True)
 End If
```

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately it takes the whole folder contents then immediately hits me with "The process cannot access the file 'C:\TestFile\encoded.zip' because it is being used by another process." Presumably because it's actually iterating through the files and one is taking longer to compress. Going to try the other solution just now. I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how ZipFile is intended to work - I see it as inputfile, outputfile and some overloads. However, it appears not quite that simple - the link does imply its for a directory not a single file. Guess its in the subs name.

Comment: marked up not as the answer to my query, but as it clarified my slight misunderstanding of the routine in question - meaning I could use the correct tool for the job. Thank you!